# javascript post fetch request gone wrong

Tags: fetch

please, help me check this post request.
I've been looking at it since yesterday, I don't know what is wrong with it
maybe I need another developer's pairs of eyes.

thanks in advance

```
buttons.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments", config)
.then(res=>{
      res.json();
  }).then(datae=>{
      console.log(datae);
  })
```

});

const config = {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify(newName)
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
buttons.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments', config)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then((datae) => {
      console.log(datae)
    })
})
```

you just need to `return res.json()`

this should work, but remember that the function you pass to the `.then` function has access to the returned value from the previous `.then`.

- fetch returns a promise that resolves into an object with the `.json` function
- so in the first `.then` it will get that object and you need to return `res.json()` which returns a promise that will be resolved to the JSON data
- so in the next `.then` you can use that data

I hope I was clear

note:

`.then` function returns a promise ( always )

also maybe you have an error in the `config` variable, what you pass to the `JSON.stringify` function should be a valid javascript object

```js
const config = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'rowadz' }),
}
```